# TypeScript, пример из учебника: вывести литеральный тип юнион из элементов массива. Почему не работает со ссылкой на массив?

Tags: массивы, typescript, динамическая-типизация

Если литерал массива задать как аргумент функции - работает как нужно. Но если передать в функцию ссылку на массив - не работает. Видимо, не понимаю чего-то фундаментального.

```
function strEnum<T extends string>(arr: T[]): {[K in T]: K}{
    return arr.reduce((res, key) => {
        res[key] = key;
        return res;
    }, Object.create(null))
}

const array = ['str', 'utr', 'dtr'];

const objFromArr = strEnum(array)
type ObjFromArr = keyof typeof objFromArr; //string | number

const objFromArr2 = strEnum(['str', 'utr', 'dtr']);
type ObjFromArr2 = keyof typeof objFromArr2; //"str" | "utr" | "dtr"
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: при передаче литерала - его тип константен, поэтому можно взять его содержимое и вывести union тип. При передаче ссылки - в массиве может быть что угодно - поэтому берется общий тип для массивов - строка и число

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, проблема понятна. Но решение какое-то корявое получается через два as.

`const array = ['str', 'utr', 'dtr'] as const;
type ArrayStr = typeof array[number];

const objFromArr = strEnum(array as unknown as ArrayStr[])
type ObjFromArr = keyof typeof objFromArr; //"str" | "utr" | "dtr"
`

Comment: а зачем второй `as`? достаточно у переменной as const добавить и все